# How can I decorate repository class in Symfony 3.4?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a task to cache doctrine result with custom keys using redis. Here is repository class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;


class JobRepository extends EntityRepository implements JobRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Job[]
     */
    public function getActiveWithCategory()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('j');

        return $qb
            ->addSelect('c')
            ->leftJoin('j.category', 'c')
            ->addCriteria(JobCriteria::active())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;


interface JobRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Job[]
     */
    public function getActiveWithCategory();
}
```

Is it possible to create Decorator for this repository and say somehow to doctrine to return needed implementation?

Or I have to create service `JobRepositoryService` which implements interface. Here I call repository methods. And then create another `JobCachedRepositoryService` which is decorator for `JobRepositoryService`. And don't use `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Job')` in whole project.

Is it right solution? How would you resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't really answer your question but you should definitely get rid of $this->getDoctrine() by injecting either your repository or entity manager as needed.  Doctrine already has some built in caching including support for Redis with an extension.  Might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cache doctrine's result with redis custom key, you can to it like that:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;


class JobRepository extends EntityRepository implements JobRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Job[]
     */
    public function getActiveWithCategory()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('j');

        $redis = new Redis();
        $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

        $cacheDriver = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache();
        $cacheDriver->setRedis($redis);
        $cacheDriver->setNamespace('some_namespace_');

        $query->setResultCacheDriver($cacheDriver);
        $query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'result_key_in_redis');

        $query =  $qb->addSelect('c')
            ->leftJoin('j.category', 'c')
            ->addCriteria(JobCriteria::active())
            ->getQuery();


        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

You can install redis lib via `pecl`.

Comment: Thanks for help! But I don't want to mess repository code. And specifying implementation (RedisCache) isn't a good idea. If I decide to change cache system I'll have to update all my code.

Comment: So why don't just wrap caching code in special service method and call it in repositories?

Comment: I created service "a" which is kind of wrapper for repository. And it implements "b" interface.

Then I created decorator for this service - "c" which implements "b" interface and calls "a" service methods and save result in cache and returns from cache if exists.

Now I'm using only interface for DI and if I dont't want to use cache, I can easily change implementation in services.yml without changing my code.